# Cannot connect to MySQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Connecting to remote MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747597/java-connecting-to-remote-mysql-database)

I'm trying to connect to MySQL database in Eclipse and Java using the following code:

```
System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
      Connection conn = null;
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
      String dbName = "RS";
      String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String userName = "root"; 
      String password = "root";
      try {
      Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
      System.out.println("Connected to the database");
      conn.close();
      System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
      } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

But, I get the following error:

```
    MySQL Connect Example.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at Expertise.main(Expertise.java:57)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the mysql jdbc driver jar to your classpath.

Answer (score 2):

Download the mysql-connector to a local directory from here http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

1. Go to Eclipse and select your project by right clicking on it.
2. Then a pop-up menu will get displayed. In there look for the item
   properties and select it.
3. The the properties window will appear, look for the item Java
   Build-path on the left select it
4. Then on the right of the window you will see a button with the "add
   library" caption. Click on it and  Look for the .jar file that you
   just downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that MySQL jar is on your class-path
2. Make sure you have the correct import in your class.